# Hibernate issue - Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I keep facing `"Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.ts.user.entity.TutRptLocYearly column: locid (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")"` issue whenever running the unit test.
I am seeking the help and advice to fix my problem, as I tried hard to fix this issue, but this error keep happen?

Below is my situation

I created 2 tables, TUT_LOCATION (Primary Key: LocID) and TUT_RPT_LOC_YEARLY (Primary Key: LocID + Year, Foreign Key: LocID). By using eclipse JPA Tools, it generated 3 class for me, tutLocation.java, tutRptLocYearly and tutRptLocYearlyPK.

[image]

TutLocation.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="tut_location")
@NamedQuery(name="TutLocation.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TutLocation t")
public class TutLocation extends InitEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer locid;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TutRptLocYearly
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tutLocation", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<TutRptLocYearly> tutRptLocYearlies;

    public TutLocation() {
    }

    public Integer getLocid() {
        return this.locid;
    }

    public void setLocid(Integer locid) {
        this.locid = locid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<TutRptLocYearly> getTutRptLocYearlies() {
        return this.tutRptLocYearlies;
    }

    public void setTutRptLocYearlies(List<TutRptLocYearly> tutRptLocYearlies) {
        this.tutRptLocYearlies = tutRptLocYearlies;
    }

    public TutRptLocYearly addTutRptLocYearly(TutRptLocYearly tutRptLocYearly) {
        getTutRptLocYearlies().add(tutRptLocYearly);
        tutRptLocYearly.setTutLocation(this);

        return tutRptLocYearly;
    }

    public TutRptLocYearly removeTutRptLocYearly(TutRptLocYearly tutRptLocYearly) {
        getTutRptLocYearlies().remove(tutRptLocYearly);
        tutRptLocYearly.setTutLocation(null);

        return tutRptLocYearly;
    }
}
```

TutRptLocYearly.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="tut_rpt_loc_yearly")
@NamedQuery(name="TutRptLocYearly.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TutRptLocYearly t")
public class TutRptLocYearly extends InitEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TutRptLocYearlyPK id;

    private Timestamp lastupdate;

    private Integer notrans;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TutLocation
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="locid")
    private TutLocation tutLocation;

    public TutRptLocYearly() {
    }

    public TutRptLocYearlyPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(TutRptLocYearlyPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastupdate() {
        return this.lastupdate;
    }

    public void setLastupdate(Timestamp lastupdate) {
        this.lastupdate = lastupdate;
    }

    public Integer getNotrans() {
        return this.notrans;
    }

    public void setNotrans(Integer notrans) {
        this.notrans = notrans;
    }

    public TutLocation getTutLocation() {
        return this.tutLocation;
    }

    public void setTutLocation(TutLocation tutLocation) {
        this.tutLocation = tutLocation;
    }

}
```

TutRptLocYearlyPK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class TutRptLocYearlyPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer locid;

    private Integer year;

    public TutRptLocYearlyPK() {
    }
    public Integer getLocid() {
        return this.locid;
    }
    public void setLocid(Integer locid) {
        this.locid = locid;
    }
    public Integer getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }
    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof TutRptLocYearlyPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        TutRptLocYearlyPK castOther = (TutRptLocYearlyPK)other;
        return 
            this.locid.equals(castOther.locid)
            && this.year.equals(castOther.year);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.locid.hashCode();
        hash = hash * prime + this.year.hashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: com.ts.user.entity.TutRptLocYearly column: locid (should
>   be mapped with insert="false" update="false")     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:830)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:848)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:870)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:605)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
>     ... 46 common frames omitted

Comment: From what i see you have 2 columns with the name "locid", one generated by the ManyToOne relationsship and your annotation `@JoinColumn(name="locid")` the other is from embedding TutRptLocYearlyPK which has locid as a primary key. You have to rename one of those.

Comment: The locid in TutRptLocYearlyPK  is a foreign key of TutLocation. Refer to the ERD, only 2 tables created, and the TutRptLocYearlyPK class is auto generated, because TutRptLocYearly will use the foreign key (locid) + Year to be its primary key.